# Look if number fails between range in column A & B then multiply original number by number in column D of same row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here is my challenge.  I need to enter a value on `C16` and then identify what range of numbers this number falls into between column **A** & **B**. I have gotten part of the way with the following command: `=VLOOKUP(C16,$A:$B,TRUE)` however it always outputs the value of the correct line that is in column **A**.
What I really want to do is enter value in `C16`, identify which line that value falls into then multiply the value in `C16` against the number in Column D of the same line that value was found on and output that answer.
Below is a sample of column A - D & Rows 2-5.  Lets say I enter the value of 10 in `C16` it should identify that falls into the range that on Row 1 then multiply the value in `C16` which is 10 in this case by `D1` resulting in an output of $1690.00

```
1       99      1    $169.00 
100     499     1    $127.00 
500     1,999   1    $78.00 
2,000   4,999   1    $58.00
```

Any and all help much appreciated!

Comment: You are using TRUE where VLOOKUP expects the "column index" - so TRUE is interpreted as 1 and you get the value from column 1....you need to use the column INDEX like this = VLOOKUP(C16,A:D,4,TRUE)....or you can use LOOKUP as per simoco's suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: 22335868 Example]

I simulated cell C16 using Cell F2 and the output in cell G2. The formula for G2 in the example above is `=SUMPRODUCT(($F$2>=$A1:$A4)*($F$2<=$B1:$B4)*$F$2*($D1:$D4))` This will display $0.00 if C16 is left blank. Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much!  This works perfect an is exactly what I was looking for! - Shawn

Answer (score 1):

If your numbers in column A are always ordered, try this one:

```
=LOOKUP(C16,A:D)*C16
```

As @barry houdini mentioned, this formula assumes that `C16` is less or equal 4999 (max value in column B of your table data)